# std::ofstream: can open file but not append

Tags: c++, linux

My program opens and writes to several files incrementally but at some seemingly arbitrary point appending text to an already existing file fails. Here's the offending piece of code:

```
bool append_to_file(std::string const &Path, std::string const &What) {
  std::ofstream FStream(Path, std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
  if (!FStream) {
    std::cerr << "OPEN FAILED" << std::endl;
    return false;
  }

  FStream << What;

  if (!FStream) {
    std::cerr << "WRITE FAILED" << std::endl;
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

When this function fails, the first check succeeds but the second doesn't and prints:
`WRITE FAILED`. The file in question definitely does exist in the filesystem both before and after the function is called and has read and write permissions set. I can't make sense of this, why would opening the file succeed but appending fail in this scenario?

EDIT: this is not reproducible given the information I've provided and should be closed.

Comment: Your function works perfectly for me, both if the file exist before and if it doesn.t. Instead of writing `WRITE FAILED`, do `std::cerr << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';` to see the error.

Comment: What is the error code on your stream?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Should it be `std::errno`?

Comment: @Barmar No....? At least I don't think so. Need to check ... Checked. No, it shall not.

Comment: @Barmar -- no. `errno` is required to be a macro. [errno]/1.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: If I try this out on it's own it works too, it doesn't work in the context of my program however, at least not always. That's why I find this hard to debug. errno is not set (I'm compiling with clang if that matters) and rdstate tells me that the fail bit is set.

Comment: @Peter Odd... Then it's hard to say. Have you tried making a small program that hammers the function until it fails and been able to reproduce the problem that way? Is there more than one thread involved?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: This is all happening in the same thread. I will try to make this reproducible somehow (at which point I'll probably have the solution because this behavior seems like it should be impossible).

Comment: @Peter :-) I know. Even if you are sure it's happening in the same thread - if you _have_ other threads in the mix somehow, you could log the thread id in the function too. Just to make sure.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Thread ID doesn't change. I don't think there _is_ a plausible explanation for this then, other than some problem with clang or libstdc++.

Comment: How large is the file? Have you run into the porblem where your file system does not support files larger than a certain size? Which begs to ask what file system type are you using?

Comment: The `failbit` indicates a `input/output operation failed (formatting or extraction error)`. What is `What` specifically?

Comment: @tobias Huh, I thought that wouldn't matter but if I try different dummy input this doesn't happen so I've added that information to the question.

Comment: @Peter Cool, but I don't understand what `What` is from your edit.

Comment: @tobias `What` is that second codeblock in string form.

Comment: @Peter is it possible for you to append to the file on the command line a few times? `echo "// Test" >> file` and see if you get the same error.

Comment: Could you include the exact "string form" it appears in? Maybe something was going weird with escaping the quote marks.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
int append_to_file(std::string const& Path, std::string const& What) {
    std::fstream FStream(Path,std::ios_base::app);
    if (!FStream) {
        std::cerr << "OPEN FAILED" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    FStream << What;

    if (!FStream) {
        std::cerr << "WRITE FAILED" << std::endl;
        return 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
int main() {
    int res = append_to_file("Tester.txt", "HIIII");
    std::cout << res;
}
```

In the example you provided, had you `#include`d `<iostream>`, `<string>` and `<fstream>`? Also, when opening with `std::ios_base::app`, you don't have to have to open with `std::ios_base::out`. Also, I changed the `return true;` and `return false;` so that it returns a number depending on where it failed. This makes it easier to trace the error. Finally, I changed `std::ofstream` to `std::fstream`, because we are opening customly. After that, it worked perfectly.